# Increase JDBC performance for bulk inserts

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sybase

Currently I have a throughput of about 350MB/hour which isn't alot. The bottleneck is the insertions into the **Sybase** database so I am looking for ways to increase the throughput.

I Can only use free JDBC drivers - none of which support driver level bulk inserts (as far as I know).

Currently I have got `autoCommit` set to false (so is transactional). Preparing statement, adding to the batch and then executing the batch every 2000 records (I have played with this number, but it doesn't help). Then commiting the transaction all the inserts have been executed.

Currently using the JTDS driver.

So I am resorting to any hacks, tips and tricks anyone has to increase the throughput.

Additional details:

- There are no triggers on the table.
- Only constraint is a public key consisting of 3 fields. (with indices)
- The statement is literally `INSERT INTO table([col],[col1],[col2],[col3]) VALUES (?,?,?,?)`

Comment: What's on the table in terms of indexes and triggers?

Comment: Is it possible to obtain an execution plan for the insert query? If so, you could analyse that and see if any gain is possible by fine-tuning your SQL.

Comment: If the data is not being accessed concurrently by other processes, could you drop any non-essential indexes / constraints before the inserts start, and reapply them when you've finished?

Comment: @NickHolt only a PK constraint.

Comment: `jTDS` AFAIK is a robust driver for MS SQL Server, and shouldn't cause performance issues in general. Single insertions vs 2000 batch-size must be giving you some benefit, what's that? What is the `JDBC` level batch-count set, if its lower then 2000 might not be in-effect. I am suspecting something to do with processing rather than driver..

Comment: @mthmulders Given that its just loading a CSV into a table, I don't see what SQL improvements could be made?

Comment: Im not sure but can stored procedures play any role on this situation?

Comment: @Ben Imagine there's some `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement, or an `INSERT` that needs up update a lot of indices with every call (like Nick Holt suggested).

Comment: I was hoping for something that worked without editing the schema.

Comment: Following might help: 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826969/multiple-queries-vs-stored-procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826969/multiple-queries-vs-stored-procedure)

Comment: Did you run a profiler on your application to check whether the bottleneck might actually be your code being to slow? (I had that once, where the limiting piece of code was actually the parser for the CSV file)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did, yes. It all into memory so that it was just doing the inserting bit and that was all.

Comment: JDBC isn't the right tool for all DB jobs - maybe this is one of those cases. Do you have scope to re-engineer the process using any native SYBASE data load utilities ( assuming there are any ). alernatively, could you scale the process horizontally by spplitting the workload across a number of threads? ( This approach will only work if you are able to separate the workload in such a way that you will limit lock contention - which miht be a bit difficult if you are dealing with just a sequential primary key )

Comment: @DaveHowes don't think threading would help here, my CPU usage is pratically NIL. Pretty sure the drivers won't be thread safe either.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into performance issues. 
I came to know that multiple queries using JDBC causes lot of network overhead on Application and Database server. Also it results in delay due to network round trips.

Please consider following. It might help:

[Multiple queries VS Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826969/multiple-queries-vs-stored-procedure)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `n/w`?

Answer (score 0):

Write a redcords in file and insert into through bcp utility. it would be much faster then what you are currenlty doing.

Comment: Interesting...might be worthwhile looking into this.